# Omit password field from User response using Grails Spring Security Plugin Core & REST

Tags: json, grails, plugins, spring-security, response

I am using **Grails 3.2.4** and the Grails **Spring Security Plugin** Core & REST. When a request is made to **User#index**, I use

```
params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
respond User.list(params), model: [userCount: User.count()]
```

The response is something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "accountExpired": false,
    "accountLocked": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "password": "$2a$10$fdWi7i48Kw5tnpzsjKMUMOQDx7nhglp9tRtDaJHTAi5qOTdIL0t3u",
    "passwordExpired": false,
    "username": "me"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "accountExpired": false,
    "accountLocked": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "password": "$2a$10$3uFrDjJ8AwMsdMbKhExece6cJtQ4DS2e1/jFMIdDHrmqgDGpBgkS2",
    "passwordExpired": false,
    "username": "master"
  },
  // ...
```

How can I customize this response and eliminate the password field, for example?

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to achieve this but the simplest would be to register a bean of type [`JsonRenderer`](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.4/api/grails/rest/render/json/JsonRenderer.html) in `resources.groovy` as below:

```
import grails.rest.render.json.JsonRenderer

beans = {
    userRenderer(JsonRenderer, User) {
        excludes = ['password']
    }
}
```

Refer https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/webServices.html#renderers for additional ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JSON-VIEWS feature in your project and your controller inherits from RestfulController you could also do the following:

Note: I am assuming that your user class is named **User**

First try and use the command

```
grails generate-views [yourpackage.]security.User
```

where [yourpackage.] is optional and represents the name of the package where you created your User class when you executed the s2-quickstart command.

If the generation of the views was succesful, you will find a directory named **user** in *\grails-app\views* with the following files

- _user.gson
- index.gson
- show.gson

These should be your json views for User. Open *_user.gson*. It should have content like the following

```
import [yourpackage.]security.User

model {
    User user
}

json g.render(user)
```

edit the code so that it excludes password from the json render

```
import [yourpackage.]security.Usuario

model {
    User user
}

json g.render(user, [excludes: ['password']) //This is where you exclude password
```

This might seem a bit more complicated than editing the beans, but in my opinion, it might be easier to look for a related view, than check the *resources.groovy* if someone else wants to edit the project.

For more information on this check the [grails reference to json views](http://views.grails.org/latest/)